# export multiple CSV files for each value/string

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a single column in a CSV file with let's say values:

```
textA
textB
textC
```

What I want to be able to do is do a loop and export each text in **its own separate CSV** file.

So as a result I would get files in my target folder like

```
file1.csv with contents textA
file2.csv with contents textB
file3.csv with contents textC
```

The basic code I am working with here is

```
$Time    = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmm"
$logFile = "C:\data\list.csv"

Import-Csv $logFile | %{
    Export-Csv "C:\export\files.2016.$currentTime.csv"
}
```

Comment: Your sample CSV has no header. Does the actual file have a header?

Comment: it doesn't but I can add one, not a problem. thanks

Comment: Since you want to split the content of one file in three separate file you need to give us more information about the content of the source file and how you want to split it (i.e. what goes where).

Comment: `% { $_ | Export-CSV "c:\export\files.2016.$($_.ColumnName).csv" -Append }` ?

Comment: This one still generated a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV means "comma separated values". You just have a list of strings, so why bother using the CSV commands? Just do something like this:

```
$i = 1
Get-Content 'list.txt' | foreach {
    Set-Content -LiteralPath "file$i.txt" -Value $_
    $i++
}
```

Comment: This is working great, I still need to figure out some output formatting but I think this method will definitely serve the purpose. Thank you very much!